# How can i access calendar from Exchange Server (.NET Framework 2.0) using WebDav

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, webdav

Now .NET Framework is up to 4.0 and but what if i'm using .NET Framework 2.0. If i want to access the calendar using WebDav, is there any library that i can use?

Comment: And what if i want to access using Outlook or Exchange Web Service(EWS), is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WebDAV .NET for Exchange](http://www.independentsoft.de/webdavex)

- Not free